# JAVA : BufferdInputStream and BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, outputstream

I have several questions-

**1.**  I have two computers connected by socket connection. When the program executes

```
outputStream.writeInt(value);
outputStream.flush();
```

what actually happens? Does the program wait until the other computer reads the integer value?

**2.** How can I empty the `outputStream` or `inputStream`? Meaning, when emptying
the `outputStream` or `inputStream`, whatever is written to that stream gets removed.
(please don't suggest to do it by closing the connection!)
I tried to empty the `inputStream` this way-

```
byte[] eatup=new byte[20*1024];
int available=0;
while(true)
{
    available=serverInputStream.available();
    if(available==0)
       break;
    serverInputStream.read(eatup,0,available);
}
eatup=null;

String fileName=(String)serverInputStream.readObject();
```

Program should not process the line as nothing else is being written on the `outputStream` .
But my program executes it anyway and throws a `java.io.OptionalDataException` error.

**Note:** I am working on a client-server file transfer project. The client sends files to
the server. The second code is for server terminal. If 'cancel button' is pressed on server
end then it stops reading bytes from the `serverInputStream` and sends a signal(I used `int`  -1)
to the client. When client receieves this signal it stops sending data to the server, but I've
noticed that `serverInputStream` is not empty. So I need to empty this `serverInputStream` so that
the client computer is able to send the server computer files again(That's why I can't manage a lock
from `read` method)

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `available` to determine how many `byte`s to read. Some implementations of `available` will always return `0`, and then your code will not work. Just try to completely fill your buffer and check the return of `read` to see how many `byte`s were actually read.

Comment: `while(serverInputStream.read(eatup,0,available)!=-1);`

Comment: @Jeffrey But if I use `read` method in this purpose, when there is no byte to read the program will block(the documentation says so) which I don't want.

Comment: @Jisean - If you need to detect an "end of message" on the receiving side without closing the connection then you need to build a basic message protocol. See my answer for an example (size prefix)

Comment: @JisanMahmud Why are you trying to discard the preexisting data on the `InputStream` anyways?

Comment: @Jeffrey Please see the additional part of my question.

Answer (score 2):

1 - No. On the flush() the data will be written to the OS kernel which will likely immediately hand it to the network card driver, which in turn will send it to the receiving end. In a nutshell the send is fire and forget.

2 - As Jeffrey commented available() is not reliable for this sort of operation. If doing blocking IO then as he suggests you should just use read() speculatively. However it should be said that you really need to define a protocol on top of the raw streams, even if it's just using DataInput/DataOutputStream. When using raw write/read the golden rule is one write != one read. For example if you were to write 10 bytes on one side and had a reading loop on the other there is no guarantee that one read will read all 10 bytes. It may be "read" as any combination of chunks. Similarly two writes of 10 bytes might appear as one read of 20 bytes on the receiving side. Put another way there is no concept of a "packet" unless you create a higher level protocol on top of the raw bytes to do packets. An example would be each send is prefixed by a byte length so the receiving side knows how much data to expect in the current packet.

If you do need to do anything more complicated than a basic apps I strongly encourage you to investigate some higher level libraries that have solved many of the gnarly issues of network IO. I would recommend [Netty](https://netty.io/) which I use for production apps. However it is quite a big leap in understanding from a simple IO stream to Netty's more event based system. There may be other libraries somewhere in the middle.

Comment: 'Defining a protocol' will be a bit high level for me, it's just my college JAVA project on 'Client-Server File Sharing'. Thanks for your info though, cleared up some confusion!

Comment: You're welcome. If you just want something basic use DataInputStream and DataOutputStream and match the reads to the writes. This will support most things you would need.